# How can I make Kendo Drop Down List to Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I want to set a value to a kendo drop down list irrespective to it's case.

For an example following code is working fine.

$("#color").data("kendoDropDownList").value("Grey");

I need it to work for following code too:

$("#color").data("kendoDropDownList").value("grey");

```js
(function() {
  var data = [{
    text: "Black",
    value: "Black"
  }, {
    text: "Orange",
    value: "Orange"
  }, {
    text: "Grey",
    value: "Grey"
  }];

  // create DropDownList from input HTML element
  $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0
  });

  var color = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
  color.value("Grey");
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="color" value="1" style="width: 100%;" />
```

Please view the fiddle for better understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/Hd47F/329/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, it makes sense that this is not working as you'd expect. You are trying to set the value, not filter the drop down list. The ignoreCase property only applies to filtering and setting the value requires exact-case from what I can see.

Instead of using `value()` to set the value, try using `search()` as below.

```
$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data, // using your same data as above
    index: 0
  });

var color = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
color.search("grey"); // This now works regardless of casing
```

You can see my example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/ewEyoC

Comment: What happens if you take `index` out?

Comment: Nothing happens. It's still requires exact case.

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer good to hear.  Please mark as answer if you feel it is resolved.

Comment: It opens the search box with the filter, but it does not set the value (as we can expect, but it's not the OP requirement). I have the same problem too, did you where able to find a solution @LonelyPlaneteer ? Thank you